# I get an annoying error on my login system

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

I am trying to make a login system for my website but there is an error comming every time i run it that says:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_system\includes\login.php on line 46.

I'v searched around the web for a sulution and tryed out a few things but it doesn't seem to be working so please help me if someone can figure it out

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>
    <?php

        $form = "<form action='login.php' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brugernavn:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='bruger' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='submit' name='logind_btn' value='Log ind' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>";


        if($_POST['logind_btn']){
                $bruger = $_POST['bruger'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                if($bruger){
                    if($password){
                        require("tilslut.php");

                        $password = md5(md5("dj4fJsd".$password."gd34aH"));
                        // vær sikker på login info er korrekt
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brugere WHERE brugernavn='$bruger'");
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 1){
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                            $dbbrugerID = $row['id'];
                            $dbbruger = $row['brugernavn'];
                            $dbpass   = $row['password'];
                            $dbactive = $row['active'];

                            if($password == $dbpass){
                                if($dbactive == 1){

                                    $_SESSION['brugerID'] = $dbbrugerID;
                                    $_SESSION['brugernavn'] = $dbbruger;

                                    echo "Du er nu logget ind som <b>$dbbruger</b>. <a href='medlem.php'>Klik her</a> for at gå til Medlems siden!";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "Du skal aktivere din konto for at logge ind. $form";

                            }
                            else
                                echo "Du intastede ikke det korrekte password. $form";

                        }
                        else
                            echo "Det intastede brugernavn blev ikke fundet. $form";


                        mysql_close();
                    }
                    else
                        echo "Du skal skrive dit password! $form";

                }
                else
                    echo "Du skal skrive et brugernavn! $form";

        }
        else
            echo $form;


    ?>
```

Comment: your query is failing, try to catch the error using `echo mysql_error($link)` where $link is the connection

Comment: as side note mysql_* functions are deprecated, look the red box at the top of the page http://us3.php.net/mysql_error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at that error message of yours:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects ...

AHA! So `mysql_num_rows()` is causing problems. Good thing you only have it once in your code, since I didn't want to count your lines finding the one causing this error

> ... expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ...

Oh, so something seems to be wrong with the parameter. Lets look closely at your code:

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

So `$query` is a boolean (true/false) - how can this be? Right, [manual always knows best](http://php.net/mysql_query)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE** on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on error.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return **FALSE** if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

So the problem is that your query probably fails and hence returns `false` which is not a valid resource but rather a boolean

---

Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information.

Comment: +1. very educational, just try adding how to catch the errors and motivate the op to use another option like mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

it Looks like the query-function returs false (query failed) and false is also given as Parameter in mysql_num_rows. there are several possible ways why the query could fail, maybe the database does not exist or something else.